# Регулярное выражение. Как найти последнее двухзначное число между пробелами?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка: ***"апавп авапа опроарп имисм 334 выаыва 33 667 88 44павап 555"***.

Должно вернуть "88". Так как "88" - последнее в строке двухзначное между пробелами число.

`\s(\d\d)\s` находит 33, т.е. поиск производит с начала строки, как с конца строки сделать поиск?

Comment: `.*` в начале добавьте, она съест все лишнее

Comment: уберите пробельный символ в конце ... `.* (\d{2})`

Comment: @MedvedevDev Если убрать пробел в конце то результат будет 55, а ТС ожидает 88

Comment: @Mike, да, не проверил регулярку, ну тогда что-то типа `.* (\d{2})(?: |$)`

Comment: `s.match/(?:^|\s)(\d{2})(?!\S|.*\s\d{2}(?!\S))/)[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно найти две последних цифры, окруженных либо пробельными символами, либо началом/концом строки.

`/.*(?:\s|^)(\d{2})(?:\s|$)/`

Answer (score 1):

Предложу обзор несколько иного решения, немного хуже предложенного по скорости и количеству шагов, но для общего развития не помешает.

В регулярных выражениях есть способ производить поиск фрагмента текста, «просматривая» (но не включая в найденное) окружающий текст, который расположен до или после искомого фрагмента текста. Таким способом легко найти имя тега HTML, не включая в результат поиска окружающие его угловые скобки или другие знаки, но и не упуская их «из внимания» при поиске нужного контекста.

Для реализации регулярного выражения мы посмотрим в сторону негативного просмотра вперед (?!) (англ. Negative Lookahead), выражение для вашего случая будет выглядеть вот так:

```
/\s(\d{2})\s(?!.*\s\d{2}\s)/
```

Заметьте, в данном выражении нет модификатора g. Данное выражение немного сложно на начальном этапе понимания регулярных выражений, но нужно понять весь смысл. Все, что заключено в операторе ?! указывает, какие символы не могут находится впереди искомого соответствия.

### Алгоритм:

Ищем совпадение двух цифр и пробелов, цифры заключаем в группу 1 (\s(\d{2})\s):

```
\s(\d{2})\s (?!.*\s\d{2}\s)
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Говорим о том, что дальше по всему тексту (.*) не может быть совпадения, где есть пробел, две цифры и еще пробел (\s\d{2}\s):

```
\s(\d{2})\s (?!.*\s\d{2}\s)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Данная операция будет повторяться, пока второе условие не станет ложно. Как только второе условие станет ложно, будет возвращен последний \s(\d{2})\s

### Выводы

Данное выражение возвращает совпадение в 1 группу, но к сожалению из-за необходимости просмотра всего текста после каждого совпадения, скорость выполнения начинает увеличиваться в зависимости от объема текста.

Решение @AndreyMakarov работает быстрее с меньшим количеством шагов.

Скорость выполнения можно проверить [здесь](https://regex101.com).